# new Date() is giving time in UTC in ec2 Instance which is configured as IST

Tags: java, datetime, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance running in Singapore zone. By default time zone for this instance is UTC. So I've set it to IST assuming, application which is running in this instance generates time in IST which we store in the database.

i.e new Date() in my application shoud return time in IST. But it's still generating time in UTC which isn't we needed.

So, how to make new Date() gives time in IST in ec2 instance without adding explicit java code?

Comment: How do you determine the time zone? `Date` doesn’t have a `getTimeZone` method (and `getTimeZoneOffset()` is deprecated).

Comment: I mean, I wanted to know, If I try to run a small program where I'm just printing new Date(), It's showing time in UTC though My Instance is configured to IST. What should I do to make my date object gives time in IST without adding additional java code? Why can't new Date() gives time in IST based in timezone set in instance?

Comment: I think you need to add more code. Now you’re at it, you may consider dropping the legacy `Date` class and using [Java 8 Data & Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead ([docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html))

Comment: No, In my old instance, when I try printing new Date(), it just give time in IST which I needed. But now, Though my instaince is IST, Date just gives time in UTC

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `-Duser.timezone="Asia/India"` as Environment Variable or run your java app with that switch from terminal using `java filename -Duser.timezone="Asia/India"`

Comment: Did that. But still it's showing time in UTC giving ouput
Tue Jan 10 10:12:49 UTC 2017. But I need this in IST

Comment: Setting the JVM’s current default time zone should only be done in extreme circumstances as that default affects all code in all apps running within that JVM. And any code in any app within the JVM can change the default again at any moment *during runtime*. Much easier to simply specify your desired/expected time zone, passing as argument to methods.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" )
)
```

## Details

The `toString` method of `Date` confusingly applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the string. This misleads you into thinking it has an assigned time zone but does not^. The `Date` object actually represents a value in UTC. One of many reasons to avoid these troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

This class is now supplanted by the java.time classes.

The Instant class represents a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Adjust into your desired time zone. Never use 3-4 letter abbreviations such as `IST`. Not a real time zone. Use [real time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

This Question is really a duplicate of many others. Search Stack Overflow for much more discussions and examples.

Do not alter the time zone of your host operating system nor the JVM’s default time zone. You simply should not rely on the default time zone as it can be changed at any moment at runtime by any code in any thread of any app within your JVM. Always specify the optional argument for time zone when calling the java.time classes, problem solved.

---

^To make things even more confusing, there actually is a time zone within the `Date` class, but without getters or setters. Used internally, but irrelevant to our discussion here. These old legacy date-time classes are a very confusing mess.